# Issue with using .take() function with spark 2+ pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, rdd

This is the code I am using. Here it runs fine without data.take but gives error when using it in pyspark python

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating
data = sc.textFile("re_u.data")
pData=data.take(2000)
ratings = pData.map(lambda l: l.split(','))\
.map(lambda l: Rating(int(l[0]), int(l[1]), float(l[2])))
```

### Gives Error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-c9c51af1b2e9> in <module>
      2 data = sc.textFile("re_u.data")
      3 pData=data.take(2000)
----> 4 ratings = pData.map(lambda l: l.split(','))\
      5  .map(lambda l: Rating(int(l[0]), int(l[1]), float(l[2])))

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Update:
After using your change @Hristo Iliev it helped but encountered another issue that followed with ratings as a list. Thank you for your help!

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating
data = sc.textFile("re_u.data")
ratings = data.map(lambda l: l.split(','))\
  .map(lambda l: Rating(int(l[0]), int(l[1]), float(l[2])))\
  .take(2000)
rank = 20
numIterations = 20
model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations)
```

Gives error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-7e35afff970b> in <module>
      1 rank = 20
      2 numIterations = 20
----> 3 model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations)

C:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\mllib\recommendation.py in train(cls, ratings, rank, iterations, lambda_, blocks, nonnegative, seed)
    271           (default: None)
    272         """
--> 273         model = callMLlibFunc("trainALSModel", cls._prepare(ratings), rank, iterations,
    274                               lambda_, blocks, nonnegative, seed)
    275         return MatrixFactorizationModel(model)

C:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\mllib\recommendation.py in _prepare(cls, ratings)
    227         else:
    228             raise TypeError("Ratings should be represented by either an RDD or a DataFrame, "
--> 229                             "but got %s." % type(ratings))
    230         first = ratings.first()
    231         if isinstance(first, Rating):

TypeError: Ratings should be represented by either an RDD or a DataFrame, but got <class 'list'>.
```

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You didn't show how you are using `ratings` initially. Please always provide the full context since that changes what the answer should be.

Comment: Please don't update your post by adding follow-up questions after your original question has been answered. Accept the answer, and ask new question under new title.

Answer (score 0):

`take()` is an action that takes the specified number elements from the top of an RDD and transfers them to the driver program. What you get from it is a Python list with the requested elements, which is:

- local to the driver, hence you should not take too many elements
- doesn't have a `map()` method simply because Python `list` class has no `map()` method

What you most likely want to do is to first apply the transformations to the `data` RDD and `take()` from the transformed RDD:

```
data = sc.textFile("re_u.data")
ratings = data.map(lambda l: l.split(','))\
  .map(lambda l: Rating(int(l[0]), int(l[1]), float(l[2])))\
  .take(2000)
```

You'll get a list of `Rating` instances.

Since you pass the data further down to ALS, which takes distributed data, i.e., an RDD, and not driver-local `list`, you have three choices:

1. Parallelise again the list, turning it into an RDD:

   ```
   data = sc.textFile("re_u.data")
   ratings = data.map(lambda l: l.split(','))\
     .map(lambda l: Rating(int(l[0]), int(l[1]), float(l[2])))\
     .take(2000)
   ratingsRDD = sc.parallelize(ratings)
   rank = 20
   numIterations = 20
   model = ALS.train(ratingsRDD, rank, numIterations)
   ```
2. Use the `sample()` method to sample a subset of the data in the RDD:

   ```
   data = sc.textFile("re_u.data")
   ratings = data.map(lambda l: l.split(','))\
     .map(lambda l: Rating(int(l[0]), int(l[1]), float(l[2])))\
     .sample(False, 0.1, 42)
   rank = 20
   numIterations = 20
   model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations)
   ```

   Here `sample(False, 0.1, 42)` means take approximately 10% of the original data and use `42` as the seed of the pseudorandom number generator. Fixing the seed will allow for reproducibility while testing. You should adjust `0.1` to the proper value so you get about 2000 samples. Notice that those samples will be taken from random places inside the RDD and will most likely not be the first 2000.
3. Emulate `take()` while staying withing the realm of RDDs:

   ```
   data = sc.textFile("re_u.data")
   ratings = data.map(lambda l: l.split(','))\
     .map(lambda l: Rating(int(l[0]), int(l[1]), float(l[2])))\
     .zipWithIndex()\
     .filter(lambda l: l[1] < 2000)\
     .map(lambda l: l[0])
   rank = 20
   numIterations = 20
   model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations)
   ```

   `zipWithIndex()` creates tuples of the RDD content where the first element comes from the RDD and the second one is the index in the RDD (essentially, the line number). You can then filter only elements with index less than 2000 and then get rid of the index using `map(lambda l: l[0])`.

Method 2 is probably the best one.

Comment: thanks for help @Hristo Iliev now I get the error ratings is a list to work with ALS function. ```rank = 20
numIterations = 20
model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations)```                                                       
Ratings should be represented by either an RDD or a DataFrame, but got <class 'list'>.

Comment: thanks! would you suggest to use list and then converting to rdd like```ratings_rdd= spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rat)```

Comment: @KaranModi I've updated the answer following your modified question.